# Oracle SQL - Could a DML statement ever cause an object to be invalid?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm working on writing some batch scripts for my company, and I see in some historical batch scripts with the following steps:

1. There is one `Delete from table where`.... statement
2. The Oracle import tool is used to import a single record
3. Recompile the schema

I don't believe you would need to recompile the schema after a delete and then import (insert).  Am I wrong?  Is it ever possible that DDL statements such as delete and insert could case an object to be invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're specifying TABLES parameter on the import? If so, you're in TABLE mode, which means that procedural objects, views, etc. are not imported. The imp command does perform a COMPILE on any PL/SQL program units that may be imported by the process. This could conceivably invalidate other dependent objects, hence the recompile step in the batch script. Of course, many times this sort of thing is put into a script based on another script that was used as a template, and could easily be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, the tables parameter is defined with a where clause.  It's quite literally, deleting a row and then re-adding it.  (It has to use IMPORT since the row contains a BLOB).

Comment: Then you should not need a database object recompile. You can of course verify that by omitting the recompile step and checking for invalid objects after the import.

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a reason why this would happen, unless your DML is messing with the data-dictionary, which sounds like a very bad idea...

As another thought, maybe the recompilation has the side-effect of doing a needed COMMIT?

Comment: There's only one delete statement deleting from a non-system table.  The other DML statement is from the Oracle import utility (which I assume performs an insert)

Comment: Triggers are a highly unlikely possibility. Maybe something to do with conditional compilation, but it seems extreme